# is it possible to retrieve simplified ratio of 2 values directly in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

So I have a table that has 2 columns `num_of_shares` and `num_of_shares_new`. `num_of_shares` has a value *10* and `num_of_shares_new` has value *12*.

Is it possible to fetch ratio between those values as **5:6** directly in a select statement without fancy functions etc.

All the solutions I found are fetching data like 1:1.2 or 0.8:1 like that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres natively supplies the function [GCD()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-math.html). You merely need to divide each by the result of that function:

```
select num_of_shares
     , num_of_shares_new 
     , (num_of_shares/gcd(num_of_shares,num_of_shares_new))::text || '/' ||
       (num_of_shares_new/gcd(num_of_shares,num_of_shares_new))::text as "Ratio"
  from shares;
```

See [domo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/U9AIwWEr);